# $cookieStore doesn't keep value after page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I'm a beginner with AngularJs and i have some trouble understanding how to use $cookieStore :/

I have a lot of buttons. Everytime a button is clicked, a distinct function is called in the controller, and in this function, i'm trying to store a value in a cookie

example :

```
$cookieStore.put('cookie', '1');
```

And at the loading of the page, i added this line :

```
alert($cookieStore.get('cookie'));
```

When we load the page for the first time, it's normal to get an "undefined" popup. But the problem is, even after clicking multiple buttons, i always got an undefined popup after refresh.

Here's a working demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/6kuqaT7ISpo7uEwLHcZn?p=preview

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your plunker cookie is setting properly :-)

Use STOP AND RUN button for refresh :P

[image]

Comment: Well ok, the problem is that, it works on Plunker, but not in local html file :/

Comment: Lol, forget, i'm just stupid. It's not working because to get it work, i need to run it on a server #FAIL

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar problem with refresh + $cookieStore some time ago, try using sessionStorage, if your target browser(s) allow that.

What Angular version do you use?

Comment: Well ok, the problem is that, it works on Plunker, but not in local html file :/ I use angularJS 1.3.15